# Is there a way to rename my subscriptions in Reeder?

Tags: macos, ios, google

Using version 1.2. I can't seem to find a way to do anything other than add subscriptions, folders and delete subscriptions. Is there any way I can just rename my existing subscriptions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to manage the feeds inside [Reeder.app](http://reederapp.com/ipad/help). Nevertheless it will synchronize all changes made to feeds **within Google Reader**. So if you want to rename a feed, open the *webpage of Google Reader* and go to the *preferences*.

[image: Choose Google Reader Preferences]

In the prefs, choose the *Abonnements tab* (at least this is the German headline) and rename the feed.

[image: Renaming]

If you now head back to the Reeder.app and synchronize your feeds the changes will be reflected and the feed will be renamed.

*Please remember that this workaround will only work **until July 1**, because Google is shutting down the Reader service.*

Comment: Thanks, Cyphorius, that's actually why I was asking. Since Google is shutting down Reader, I was wondering how I would do this in the future. I hope the Reeder people decide to include this option in a future release.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible to **edit** subscriptions on Reeder. You will need to login to your RSS, or news feed account to edit subscriptions.

Please go ahead and [contact their support](http://reederapp.com/iphone/contact) to request the ability to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can now (on iPhone Reeder app) rename individual subscriptions by long-pressing on them in the folder view. For some reason, clicking on the feed and going into the three-dot settings menu gives you lots of ways to customize the display of the subscription but not rename it.